# TextView on different displays

Tags: android

Help to understand please.
I need to show up in a specific box.
I do it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fon"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

....

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

....
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Everything works at four inch screen well but if  take a big diagonal, it will be bad. 
At increase in the screen the textView size doesn't change.
I use "dp" and "sp", instead of static "px", but does not work...
Why Is this happening ?

screenshots:

[4 inch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcDQM.jpg)

[5.4 inch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQhUU.jpg)

Comment: Try using dip (display independent pixel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different resource directories for different screen sizes and densities and then create `dimens.xml` in each of them providing text size to be used on specific screen size, for example:

*res/values-sw420dp/dimens.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="font_size">26sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

*res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="font_size">30sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

*res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="font_size">36sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And then call it in your layout file:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
```

---

**This is a solution for the text size, but you can do the same thing for width and height.**

More resources:

- [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)
- [Dimension Resource Type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)
- [Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

The text view size is static because you have defined a fixed size to them.Use wrap content.

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: If  use "wrap_content", the text will take all place on the screen, and it is necessary that it was in a certain square

Comment: looks like your post gets more serial upvotes at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust the TextView android:layout_width and android:layout_height to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

If you want the TextView to center inside the white background, you should add another attribute

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: If  use "wrap_content", the text will take all place on the screen, and it is necessary that it was in a certain square